# How to create database with .sql file in visual studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2010

I downloaded a asp.net webform application off the internet and it included a .sql file to create the database and tables. I'm new to asp.net/visual studio and kind of stuck with this for days now. Need help.

here's the content of the web.config

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConsString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=myslideshow; Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="10240000" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: open the .sql file in sql server and press f5 or press execute button in window authentication

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the file with .sql extension in visual studio
2. Right Click
3. Execute script

Comment: No option to execute script

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the SQL file
2. use CTRL-SHIFT-E